# problema doctest en shell

Tags: python, doctest

Al realizar el programa con doctest y ejecutarlo, no aparece en shell la ejecución del doctest diciendo que los tests han pasado o si hay algun fallo.

Mi función:

```
def maxim4(a,b,c,d):
   """
>>> maxim4(1,2,3,4)
4
>>> maxim4(11,23,4,1)
11
>>>maxim4(1,45,11,2)
45

   """


   if a>b and a>c and a>d:
      return(a)
   elif b>a and b>c and b>d:
      return(d)
   elif c>a and c>b and c>d:
      return(c)
   else:
      return(d)

   if __name__=="__main__":
      import doctest
      doctest.testmod (verbose= True)
```

Comment: ¿La línea `if __name__=="__main__":` y las siguientes líneas están dentro de la función o afuera `maxim4`? Deben estar afuera

Answer (score 2):

El indentación es importante. Ahora el bloque `if __name__=="__main__":` está dentro de la función `maxim4`, por lo que cuando se inicia el módulo, no se llama a la función `maxim4` en sí. Es necesario eliminar los márgenes adicionales. También debe agregar un espacio adicional después de `>>>` en la línea `>>>maxim4(1,45,11,2)`.

Código corregido:

```
def maxim4(a,b,c,d):
   """
>>> maxim4(1,2,3,4)
4
>>> maxim4(11,23,4,1)
11
>>> maxim4(1,45,11,2)
45
   """

   if a>b and a>c and a>d:
      return(a)
   elif b>a and b>c and b>d:
      return(d)
   elif c>a and c>b and c>d:
      return(c)
   else:
      return(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import doctest
   doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Devuelve:

```
Trying:
    maxim4(1,2,3,4)
Expecting:
    4
ok
Trying:
    maxim4(11,23,4,1)
Expecting:
    11
**********************************************************************
File "/home/user/test_doctest.py", line 5, in __main__.maxim4
Failed example:
    maxim4(11,23,4,1)
Expected:
    11
Got:
    1
Trying:
    maxim4(1,45,11,2)
Expecting:
    45
**********************************************************************
File "/home/user/test_doctest.py", line 7, in __main__.maxim4
Failed example:
    maxim4(1,45,11,2)
Expected:
    45
Got:
    2
1 items had no tests:
    __main__
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   3 in __main__.maxim4
3 tests in 2 items.
1 passed and 2 failed.
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```